# A rational function on a dense subset of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

if we have two element $\frac{f}{g}$,$\frac{f'}{g'}$ $\in K(X)$ where $K(X)$ is rational function on variety "X",then if $\frac{f}{g}=\frac{f'}{g'}$ on an open dense subset U of X (with zariski topology), can we say that this two elements are equal in all of X? if yes, how? and if no,  why?

what about two elements of coordinate ring $A(X)$ ?

thanks

Comment: Do you define a variety to be an _irreducible_ algebraic set? (like in Hartshorne)

Comment: Yes i defined it as irreducible algebraic sets

Comment: Could you please also tell us how you're defining $K(X)$ and $A(X)$? And also, when you say that $f/g = f'/g'$ are equal in all of $X$, do you mean that $f(x)/g(x) = f'(x)/g'(x)$ for all $x \in X$? (This isn't quite possible because there will be some $x \in X$ where $g(x) = 0$ or $g'(x) = 0$, hence $f/g$ or $f'/g'$ won't be defined at these points.)

Comment: However, following is a true statement, and may (or may not) help: "If $X$ is an affine variety and $f, g, f'$ and $g' $ are polynomial functions on $X$, and $U$ and $V$ are non-open subsets of $X$ where $g$ (respectively $g'$) do not vanish. Then we can think of $f/g$ as a  function on $U$ and $f'/g'$ as a  function on $V$. Now suppose that $W$ is a non-empty open subset of  $U \cap V$. Suppose I tell you that $f(x)/g(x) = f'(x)/g'(x)$ for all $x \in W$. Then it is true that $f(x) / g(x) = f'(x)/g'(x)$ for all $x \in U \cap V$." Is this the kind of statement you're looking for?

Comment: the subsets :"U" and "V" should be open , cause open subsets (of a variety=irreducible algebraic set) are dense in Zariski topology, your description is wright if you consider them open subsets and also you should conclude that two above functions are equal in all of X not only the intersection of U and V. that's my question

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to write "non-empty open"!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that they are equal on all of $X$, since $f/g$ is not defined when $g(x) = 0$ and $f'/g'$ is not defined when $g'(x) = 0$. The best you can do is show that $f/g$ and $f'/g'$ are equal wherever they are defined. This follows from the statement I gave you.

Comment: ... and to prove my statement: First, note that the subset of $U \cap V$ on which $f(x)/g(x) \neq f'(x)/g'(x)$ is open, since it is the complement of the vanishing locus of the polynomial $g'f - gf'$. Since $X$ is _irreducible_, it follows that this set is either empty or dense. However, this set clearly doesn't intersect with the non-empty open set $W$, so it is not dense, and hence it is empty, as required.